# Is there a service to withdraw dollars by wire transfer with small fees?

Tags: exchanges, withdrawal

I need to make a bank transfer to a US bank account and found out that MTGOX is asking for 2000 CNY fee. That is too much since the amount of money I want to transfer is smaller than that.

Is there any exchange service with smaller fees?

Answer (score 1):

Take out to Dwolla (FREE Account), then move to bank account for a flat fee of  $0.25.  I use to use them all the time like that.

Fee list from Dwolla:
https://www.dwolla.com/fees

MtGox doesn't charge anything to send to Dwolla, they just charge you to transfer from BTC to Dollar's. But it's cheaper than what it was for ACH transfer.

Comment: Dwolla is asking me for a phone number. What do I do if I don't live in the US?

Comment: How in the world do you have a bank account in the US without a phone number? Sign up for a US phone number at a service like localphone.com, $0.99 a month for US based number.

Comment: I don't have a bank account in the US. I need to send money to one.

Comment: How about sending the owner of the account the bitcoins, and letting them do the cash out if they choose.

Comment: The company doesn't accept bitcoins and was strict with that. I'd love if somebody could do the work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the funds don't need to arrive same-day, withdraw USDs via ACH at BitFloor and Camp BX.  Simply enter routing # and account number.  It is not the same thing as a wire transfer, so you would want to make sure your counterparty will accept ACH transfers.

You can even order rush ACH through BitFloor.

If you do need to do a wire (e.g., same-day transfer), a lot of exchanges offer than, with varying fees.